# PHP check array contain multiple sub arrays with data array OR just one data array

Tags: php, arrays

I got a array call back from API and I need parse it.
Sometimes it return a single data array like this

```
array{
   [name] => aaa
   [address] => bbb
   [country] => ccc
}
```

OR sometimes it return multiple data arrays like this

```
array{
   [0]=>array{
      [name] => aaa
      [address] => bbb
      [country] => ccc
   }

   [1]=>array{
      [name] => qqq
      [address] => www
      [country] => eee
   }

   [2]=>array{
      [name] => ttt
      [address] => yyy
      [country] => uuu
   }
}
```

What is the best way to determine that return array contain multiple arrays?
Or what is the if statement for it?
I know how to write a function and return is or not. like foreach then check is_array then return
But is there any express way or php function can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `isset` to know wether or not the first index is a number (multi-dimensional) or not (uni-dimensional):

```
if (isset($array[0]) {
    // Since the index is 0 but not the key 'name'
    // The array is multi-dimensional
} else {
    // Since the first index is not 0, the array is
    // uni-dimensional
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `name` key always exists, you can check if it's set at the first level, and if so you have a single value array.

```
if(array_key_exists('name',$array)) {
  //single
}
elseif(isset($array[0]) && array_key_exists('name',$array[0])) {
  //multi
}
else {
  //neither!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered, but a broader approach not relying on whether indexes are numeric or not:

```
if(is_array(reset($array)) {
    // multi-dimensional
} else {
    // single-dimensional
}
```